# Set range of allowed datatypes / type cast for values from file in python

Tags: python, dynamic, types, casting

I am reading in a file line by line. Lines are delimited with "|". Since values are interpreted as string once they were read from the file I want to cast them to their correct representation (I now the datatype of each "column" value).

Thus, I wrote a little "translate" method that looks like the following:

```
def translateType(self, dataType):
    if dataType == "INTEGER":
       return int
    elif dataType == "FLOAT":
       return float
    elif dataType == "STRING":
       return str
```

I think that this is not really a satisfying solution, because this code is somehow not very ugly and gets a pain when there are more datatypes to be supported.

Do you have any ideas how to make this sort of "type-setting" somehow better and more extendable?

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary, e.g.

```
def translateType(t):
    return {"INTEGER": int, "FLOAT": float, "STRING": str}.get(t, None)
```

Or, if performance is imperative (profile first), define the dict in the argument list so it doesn't need to be created each time the function is called:

```
def translateType(t, types={"INTEGER": int, "FLOAT": float, "STRING": str}):
    return types.get(t, None)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. :) Although, dictioonary?

Comment: You say elsewhere that the data types are specified in the file... I assume the field names are as well. In that case, you could create a mapping directly from the field name to its Python type and leave out the middlemen types.

Comment: Hi - jup, but when reading the second line of the file giving int, float and str instead of the above mentioned middlemen types, than python will store this information in a string again he?

Comment: You still have to pass the read type through the type conversion dictionary when you read it initially, but you only have to do it once instead of when processing each line. That's all I was suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of strings, just use a list of the field types directly:

```
>>> line = 'white fang|jack london|1888|7.50'
>>> types = [str, str, int, float]
>>> [t(s) for t, s in zip(types, line.split('|'))]
['white fang', 'jack london', 1888, 7.5]
```

Comment: Hi - yeah good idea... but the information of the fields type is actually coming from the file itself (second line). Thus, i do not know it during "compile" time